# cannot use current_user in jinja2 macro?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I use Flask-Login which provides the `current_user` object in templates. I want to write a macro to show a comment form or a log in link depending on if the user is logged in.  If I  use this code directly in the template, it works:

```html
{% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ quick_form(form) }}
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Log In with Github</a>
{% endif %}
```

I placed the same code in a macro and import the macro in my template.

```html
{% macro comment_form(form) %}
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

```html
{% from "macros/comments.html" import comment_form %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {# ... content goes here ... #}
    {{ comment_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I try to load this page, the error I get is:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'current_user' is undefined
```

Of course, the easy workaround is to pass in `current_user` as a parameter and use that (making the signature `comment_form(user, form)`), although this is a fairly ugly solution (imo).

Why doesn't the macro use the context processor?  Does it not hold the context?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The context a template is rendered in is not passed to imports unless instructed to do so.  See the [relevant docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/templates/#import-context-behavior).

You're right, you don't need to inject context as arguments to macros.  You can import the macros `with context` and they will have access the the context of the template they're imported in.

```html
{% from "macros/comments.html" import comment_form with context %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `current_user.is_authenticated` is now accessed as a property and calling the method definition will lead to problems with more up-to-date library versions.

***See:*** https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.current_user

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE: This is an incorrect answer according to OP's requirements.

According to [jinja2 docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#macros) not every variable is available in jinja2 macros. Change your macro and send ’current_user’ as a parameter to it:

```
% macro comment_form(form, current_user, disabled=False) %}
{% if current_user.is_authenticated() %}
  {{ quick_form(form) }}
{% else %}
  <p class="text-muted">You are not signed in. Please <a href="{{ url_for('auth.login') }}">Sign In With Github</a> to continue
  </p>
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

and this is how your will use it:

```
{% from "macros/comments.html" import comment_form %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  {# ... content goes here ... #}
  {{ comment_form(form, current_user) }}
{% endblock %}
```