# moment is undefined in flask-moment

Tags: python, flask, momentjs

In my recent project I chose flask-moment instead of moment.js. However, it keeps appearing `UndefinedError: 'moment' is undefined`.

I used factory pattern like this:

```
from config import config
from exts import babel, db, login_manager, mail, moment

def create_app(config_name):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    ...

    moment.init_app(app)

    return app
```

I do add `{{ moment.include_moment() }}` at the end of my `base.jinja2` file, and it's successful loaded. I wrote a `components.jinja2` that contains this piece of code:

```
{% macro render_file_thumbnail(file) %}
<div class="">
    <hr>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
            <a href="{{ url_for('people.profile', user_id=file.uploader.id ) }}">
                <img class="media-object file-th-avatar img-rounded" src="{{ file.uploader.avatar }}" alt="{{ file.uploader.nickname }}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h6 class="file-th-header">
                <a href="{{ url_for('file.file_display', page_number=1, file_id=file.id) }}">
                    {{ file.file_name }}
                </a>
            </h6>
            <p>
                <span class="text-muted fa fa-fw fa-institution"></span>
                <a href="{{ url_for('course.course', course_id=file.course.id, page_number=1) }}">
                    {{ file.course.course_name }}
                </a>
                <span class="text-muted fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></span>
                {{ file.author }}
                <span class="text-muted fa fa-fw fa-download"></span>
                {{ file.downloaded_times}} {{ _('time(s)') }}
                <span class="text-muted fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"></span>
                {{ moment(file.uploaded_time).fromNow(refresh=True) }}
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

I import it to render templates, and the error emerges.

But if I use `{% include %}` instead of marco, the problem is fixed! So how can I keep using marco and fix the problem at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is not passed to macro if you did not instruct it. You could fix this by importing macro with context

```
{% from "your_macro_file" import render_file_thumbnail with context %}
```

Please refer to [doc](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-context-behavior) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339583/cannot-use-current-user-in-jinja2-macro)